# Listing variables in current and higher frames

Tags: perl, debugging, stack-trace, stack-frame

I'm trying to debug a script with `perl -d ...`. After I break where I want, I'd like to print out the current environment and the environment from higher frames.

I see the stack via `T`. Now, if I try `V`, I get a list of everything, which is pretty much useless, since it includes stuff like `SO_BROADCAST` constants, etc. How can I filter those out and get only local ones?

How do I do the same for higher frames?

Also, how do I print the code around the line of a higher stack frame? `v` / `l` do only the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `y [level]`, which shows the lexical (my) variables at the current or higher (specified by `level`)?

Provided that's what you mean by "getting only local ones", of course.

Comment: But what is `level`? Is it the same as stack frame number? Which way are they numbered?

Comment: By analogy with the caller() interface, 0 = current frame, 1 = the one above, etc.

Comment: When I try the "y" command I am told I must install PadWalker, per Eric Strom's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [PadWalker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PadWalker) module to give you a list of lexicals at a given scope.  The `peek_my` and `peek_our` functions return a hashref of the variables in scope at a relative call frame (0 - current frame, 1 - calling frame, ...)